# How do I use Entity Framework instead of Ado.net for stored procedure?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I am using a stored procedure in my SQL Server database to take input of the data through the datatable. As I am using ASP.NET MVC now, I want to use Entity Framework instead of ado.net

```
public void BulkUpload(DataTable dt)
{
        dt.TableName = "MainTable";
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DatatableToDataBase", conn);

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "MainTB";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Details", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dt;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }
```

Comment: For this, I prefer to use Dapper instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy just add an entity datamodel to your program

connect to you model :

```
"entitymodel" context = this.CurrentDataSource;
```

And pass the stored procedure where you like .

Thats everything

Example:

```
[WebGet]
    public List<callersW> GetCaller()
    {

        testCDREntities1 context = this.CurrentDataSource;

        //sql parameters here

        List<callersW> result = context.Database.SqlQuery<callersW>("StoredProcedure").ToList();
        return result;


    }
```